# 3 virtual host serving same page when browsing to specific domain name

Tags: virtualhost, debian-wheezy

I have Webmin on Debian. I want to add 3 domain names to the virtualhost but for some reason all 3 domain names serve the same page when browsing to the domain names.The page that shows on all 3 websites is the `index.php` test file I placed on `itnerd.nl`. How to fix this?

This is what i get when using `apachectl -S`

```
    VirtualHost configuration:
[2001:41d0:8:e2a1::1]:80 is a NameVirtualHost
     default server itnerd.nl (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/itnerd.nl.conf:1)
     port 80 namevhost itnerd.nl (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/itnerd.nl.conf:1)
178.32.223.161:80      is a NameVirtualHost
     default server itnerd.nl (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/itnerd.nl.conf:1)
     port 80 namevhost itnerd.nl (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/itnerd.nl.conf:1)
wildcard NameVirtualHosts and _default_ servers:
*:80              www.thememonster.nl (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/www.thememonster.nl.conf:1)
Syntax OK
```

Comment: show us the contents of the configuration files shown by `apachectl -S`

Answer (score 0):

Here are the following 2 config files:

```
<VirtualHost 178.32.223.161:80 [2001:41d0:8:e2a1::1]:80>
```

SuexecUserGroup "#1003" "#1002"
ServerName itnerd.nl
ServerAlias www.itnerd.nl
ServerAlias webmail.itnerd.nl
ServerAlias admin.itnerd.nl
DocumentRoot /home/itnerd/public_html
ErrorLog /var/log/virtualmin/itnerd.nl_error_log
CustomLog /var/log/virtualmin/itnerd.nl_access_log combined
ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /home/itnerd/cgi-bin/
ScriptAlias /awstats/ /home/itnerd/cgi-bin/
DirectoryIndex index.html index.htm index.php index.php4 index.php5

Options -Indexes +IncludesNOEXEC +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch +ExecCGI
allow from all
AllowOverride All Options=ExecCGI,Includes,IncludesNOEXEC,Indexes,MultiViews,SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
AddType application/x-httpd-php .php
AddHandler fcgid-script .php
AddHandler fcgid-script .php5
FCGIWrapper /home/itnerd/fcgi-bin/php5.fcgi .php
FCGIWrapper /home/itnerd/fcgi-bin/php5.fcgi .php5


allow from all
AllowOverride All Options=ExecCGI,Includes,IncludesNOEXEC,Indexes,MultiViews,SymLinksIfOwnerMatch

RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} =webmail.itnerd.nl
RewriteRule ^(.*) https://itnerd.nl:20000/ [R]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} =admin.itnerd.nl
RewriteRule ^(.*) https://itnerd.nl:10000/ [R]
RemoveHandler .php
RemoveHandler .php5
php_admin_value engine Off
FcgidMaxRequestLen 1073741824

AuthName "itnerd.nl statistics"
AuthType Basic
AuthUserFile /home/itnerd/.awstats-htpasswd
require valid-user

Alias /dav /home/itnerd/public_html

DAV on
AuthType Basic
AuthName "itnerd.nl"
AuthUserFile /home/itnerd/etc/dav.digest.passwd
Require valid-user
ForceType text/plain
Satisfy All
RemoveHandler .php
RemoveHandler .php5
RewriteEngine off

And the other one:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
```

DocumentRoot "/home/thememonster.nl/public_html"
ServerName www.thememonster.nl

allow from all
Options None

I also had a virtual host for itmonsters.tk but i removed it. Still when i go to itmonsters.tk and thememonster.nl i get the index page which only needs to be shown for itnerd.nl.
Any fix for this?